# Setting Adaptive Layout to all iPhone Screen Sizes

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout, screen-size, adaptive-layout

I want my application screen to look same in all iPhones screen sizes i.e

3.5 inch
4 inch
4.7 inch
5.5 Inch

Display Devices
I am stuck in setting its auto layout constraint

Here's how my screen looks like:

[image]

Can Anyone help me?

Comment: You can set multiplier for all constraints, than it will work perfectly

Comment: Are you using size classes?

Comment: nope how to so.